# Where is the place UOW commit method should be call?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In our application we use Unit of work,Repository pattern ,MVC3,EF4 POCO  ..So I think we should use unit of work commit method @ the service layer because the domain logic going to there .So could you give me some advise about it

Answer (score 1):

No, IMO the **Controller** should perform the Commit, since it's what's responsible for updating the model.

Although the service layer may indeed invoke methods on the domain/repository, it only responds to requests from the Controller.

Only the Controller knows when it's *finished*, so it should invoke the Commit. Usually this is right at the end of the action method, prior to performing a redirect.

In a web scenario, there usually should be only one unit of work per HTTP request, whilst there may be *multiple services* per HTTP request.

So what i and most others do is instantiate a new UoW for each HTTP request, and pass this along to the Repository so even if you have multiple repositories, they are still wrapped by a single UoW (aka database connection).

Ideally you should use a DI/IoC container to do this.

Comment: If you use commit in controller and say we are going to integrate same service Layer with WCF service .Then Then this UOW commit should be done in that service also .. So That My feeling is the Uof should be commit in Service layer ....

Comment: @user1012062 - well you didnt mention that in your question. Perhaps expand your question to indicate the architecture in place.